# how to convert mysql join query to Drupal 7 db_select join query

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to convert the below mysql query to db_select in drupal 7.

```
            SELECT ws.sid, u.name AS username, r.name AS role,
        DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.created), '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'created', 
        DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.login), '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'last_login',
        DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.access), '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'last_accessed'  
        FROM users u
        INNER JOIN users_roles ur ON ur.uid = u.uid
        INNER JOIN role r ON r.rid = ur.rid
        INNER JOIN webform_submissions ws ON ws.uid = u.uid
        WHERE u.login <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AND r.name IN ('elev', 'lærer')
        ORDER BY last_login ASC


  Can anyone please suggest how to write it?
```

Comment: You can use db_query instead of db_select

Comment: can you please let me know how to convert this query to db_query?

Comment: What have you tried already? The drupal database api is documented [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/database-api-overview)

Answer (score 0):

Use [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x)

```
db_query("Your query here")->fetchAll();   //output as objects
db_query("Your query here")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //output as arrays
```

For your sql query.

```
db_query("SELECT ws.sid, u.name AS username, r.name AS role,
        DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.created), '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'created', 
        DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.login), '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'last_login',
        DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.access), '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'last_accessed'  
        FROM users u
        INNER JOIN users_roles ur ON ur.uid = u.uid
        INNER JOIN role r ON r.rid = ur.rid
        INNER JOIN webform_submissions ws ON ws.uid = u.uid
        WHERE u.login <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AND r.name IN ('elev', 'lærer')
        ORDER BY last_login ASC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: can we write this query in db_select as i don't want to pass raw mysql query ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
$query = db_query("SELECT ws.sid, u.name AS username, r.name AS role, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.created), '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'created', DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.login), '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'last_login', DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.access), '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'last_accessed'  
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN users_roles ur ON ur.uid = u.uid
    INNER JOIN role r ON r.rid = ur.rid
    INNER JOIN webform_submissions ws ON ws.uid = u.uid
    WHERE u.login <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AND r.name IN ('elev', 'lærer')
    ORDER BY last_login ASC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<pre>";print_r($query);exit; //to check the result
```